# How to adjust custom colormap for 3D shades based on degradation of a color tone

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, tikz-styles

I have this figure:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,enlargelimits=false,xlabel=$a_1$,ylabel=$a_2$] 
    \addplot [blue!80!black,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.4]
coordinates
{(0., 0.) (0., 0.2629952) (0., 0.43830780032) (0.1096032496, 
 0.43830780032) (0.6572250048, 0.26310039808) (0.657488, 0.)}
|- (axis cs:0,0) -- cycle;


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to use different grades (a custom colormap) for this 3 D figure:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view/v=25,view/h=110,xlabel=$a_1$,ylabel=$a_2$,zlabel=$a_3$,
    colormap/greenyellow,
    xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,zmin=0,zmax=1, grid=major]
\addplot3[%xmin=0,xmax=1,
    opacity=0, 
    fill opacity=0.6,
    table/row sep=\\,
    patch,
    patch type=polygon,
    vertex count=3,
    patch table with point meta={%
    % pt1 pt2 pt3 pt4 pt5 cdata
      0 1   2   1. \\
      2 3   0   3. \\
      0 3   4   2. \\
      3 2   4   2.12132 \\
      2 1   4   3.53553 \\
      1 0   4   2. \\
      }
]
table {
    x y z\\
    0   0   0 \\
    0   0   0.657488 \\
    0   0.657488    0 \\
    0.657488    0   0 \\
    0.657488    0   0.657488 \\
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

based on grades of the first plot color: `blue!80!black`. 
For example, how I can create colormap ranging from `blue!20!black` to `blue!80!black`, in for example 8 or 9 levels?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view/v=25,view/h=110,xlabel=$a_1$,ylabel=$a_2$,zlabel=$a_3$,
    colormap={darkblue}{color=(blue!20!black) color=(blue!80!black)},
    xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,zmin=0,zmax=1, grid=major]
\addplot3[%xmin=0,xmax=1,
    opacity=0, 
    fill opacity=0.6,
    table/row sep=\\,
    patch,
    patch type=polygon,
    vertex count=3,
    patch table with point meta={%
    % pt1 pt2 pt3 pt4 pt5 cdata
      0 1   2   1. \\
      2 3   0   3. \\
      0 3   4   2. \\
      3 2   4   2.12132 \\
      2 1   4   3.53553 \\
      1 0   4   2. \\
      }
]
table {
    x y z\\
    0   0   0 \\
    0   0   0.657488 \\
    0   0.657488    0 \\
    0.657488    0   0 \\
    0.657488    0   0.657488 \\
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How many levels of shades between both colors can be?.

Comment: @user1993416 You can have arbitrarily many. Try for instance`colormap={darkblue}{color(1)=(blue!20!black) color(2)=(blue!30!black)
 color(3)=(blue!60!black) color(4)=(blue!80!black)},`

Comment: Finally I am using this `colormap={darkblue}{color(1)=(blue!80!black!90) color(2)=(blue!80!black!70) color(3)=(blue!80!black!50) color(4)=(blue!80!black!30)}`.